# Prove $f$ is integrable if $f_n: E \to \mathbb{R}$ if $m(A) < \delta$ for all measurable $A \subset E$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ have finite Lebesgue measure $m(E)<\infty, f_n:E \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall n \geq 1$ and any measurable set $A \subset E$ with $m(A)<\delta, \int_A|f_n|dm < \epsilon$.  Let $f_n \to f$ point wise are on E.  Prove $f$ is integrable over $E$.

I know that $|\int_A f dm | < |\int_A f dm| < \epsilon$ and I'm guessing we want to use LDCT, but I don't see how.  Are we supposed to switch to a countable union of subsets of E?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Egorov's theorem. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By uniform integrability, there is $\delta > 0$, such that $$\int_E \lvert f_n\rvert d\mu < \epsilon, \,\,\,\, \text{ whenever } \mu(E) < \delta, \,\,\,\,\, \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb N.$$ Since $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., by Egorov's theorem, there is a measurable set $U \subset X$, such that $\mu(X\setminus U) < \delta$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $U$. Since $\mu(U) \le \mu(X) < \infty,$ by uniform convergence on $U$, for large enough $n$, we have $$\sup_{x \in U} \lvert f_n - f\rvert < \epsilon/\mu(U).$$ Thus for large enough $n$, \begin{align*}\int_X \lvert f_n - f \rvert d\mu&= \int_U \lvert f_n - f \rvert d\mu + \int_{X\setminus U} \lvert f_n - f \rvert d\mu \\ 
&\le \int_U \frac{\epsilon}{\mu(U)} d\mu + \int_{X\setminus U} \lvert f_n\rvert d\mu + \int_{X\setminus U} \lvert f\rvert d\mu \le 3\epsilon.
\end{align*} This shows that $\int_X \lvert f_n - f\rvert d\mu \to 0$. Then integrating the inequality $\lvert f \rvert \le \lvert f_n \rvert + \lvert f - f_n\rvert$ shows that $f$ is integrable.

(Note: to claim that $\int_{X\setminus U} \lvert f \rvert d\mu \le \epsilon$, I used Fatou's lemma: $\int_{X\setminus U} \lvert f \rvert d\mu \le \liminf \int_{X\setminus U} \lvert f_n \rvert d\mu \le \epsilon$, and the last inequality holds because $\mu(X\setminus U) < \delta$)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with Lebesgue measure on the line you can find a partition $\{A_1,\ldots,A_m\}$ of $A$ with the property that $\mu(A_k) < \delta$ for each $k$. Consequently by Fatou's lemma
$$\int_A |f| \, d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^m \int_{A_k} |f| \, d\mu \le \sum_{k=1}^m \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_k} |f_n| \, d\mu \le \sum_{k=1}^m \epsilon = m \epsilon.$$